# loading the image from "PHP Runner" to the ImageView in android

Tags: android

I have **PHPRunner** in my device and it is like **Wamp Server** with the difference that **PHP Runner** is for android and It should be as follows to use it:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/
```

I want to load an image from the `http://127.0.0.1:8080/apps/image.jpg` inside an **ImageView** using the following code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
WebView webView;
ImageView imageView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(88,255,114));
    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    imageView.setImageURI(Uri.parse("http://127.0.0.1:8080/apps/image.jpg"));

    }
```

but it can not load the image.What is the solution?

Comment: You can use BitmapFactory.decodeStream to decode image and use imageView.setImageBitmap. Link to documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeStream(java.io.InputStream)

Answer (score 1):

ImageView will not load images over the network. You need to either download it yourself or use libraries like Glide, Picasso or Fresco.